# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when using restore_best_weights=True in EarlyStopping keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, typeerror

I am new to using keras for deep learning applications. I am trying to perform binary classification using pre-trained models. I am running the code in google colab where the tensorflow version is **2.2.0-rc2**. The following is the model I am using.

```
vgg19_basemodel = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top = False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(IMSIZE,IMSIZE,3))
#vgg19_basemodel.summary()

x = vgg19_basemodel.output

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

for layer in vgg19_basemodel.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

vgg19_model = tf.keras.Model(vgg19_basemodel.input, x)
vgg19_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#vgg19_model.summary()
```

The following are the callbacks I am using.

```
class myCallBack(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if(logs.get('loss') <= EXLOSS and logs.get('accuracy') >= EXACC and logs.get('val_accuracy') >= VALACC):
      print("\nCALLBAKC: TRAINING LOSS {} reached.".format(EXLOSS))
      self.model.stop_training  = True

ccall = myCallBack()

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', min_delta=0.01, baseline = 0.01, patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
```

I am training the model using the following:

```
d3_vgg19_history = vgg19_model.fit(d3_train_generator, 
                          epochs=EPOCHS,
                          validation_data=d3_test_generator, 
                          steps_per_epoch=d3_stepsize_train, 
                          validation_steps=d3_stepsize_test,
                          callbacks=[ccall, es]
                          )
```

The custom callback doesn't produce any problem and stops training perfectly when used without early stopping.

However, if I set the **restore_best_weights=True** in early stopping, the following error is generated when **epoch_number == patience**.

If I set  **restore_best_weights=False**, no problems occur and training ends successfully.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-f6a9ab9579ae> in <module>()
      6                           steps_per_epoch=d3_stepsize_train,
      7                           validation_steps=d3_stepsize_test,
----> 8                           callbacks=[ccall, esd3]
      9                           )

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    811           epoch_logs.update(val_logs)
    812 
--> 813         callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    814         if self.stop_training:
    815           break

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    363     logs = self._process_logs(logs)
    364     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 365       callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    366 
    367   def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
   1483           if self.verbose > 0:
   1484             print('Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.')
-> 1485           self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
   1486 
   1487   def on_train_end(self, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1517         expected_num_weights += 1
   1518 
-> 1519     if expected_num_weights != len(weights):
   1520       raise ValueError(
   1521           'You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "%s" '

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I have tested the early stopping in other pre-trained models, namely: vgg16, denset201, resnet, xception, inception, etc. However, the problem with the EarlyStopping persists and the same errors pop up whenever restore_best_weights is set to True. 
Thanks in advance for helping me out in this case. Let me know if any other information is necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the "problem".
It makes sense it is None because it found no better model than the baseline in my case.
I got rid of "baseline=1.0" and now it works for me.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time! I was using a realistic baseline. And this cryptic message supposedly indicates something related to the baseline (though the model is below and go to epoch 100). Got rid of the baseline and the message disappeared (fingers crossed).